# Java code design dilemma

Tags: java, spring

I have a dilemma regarding the design of my code.

First of all, I am converting a VB to Java system.
The VB program has a class module which is like a combination of POJO and access the database for its logic. I created a similar class in JAVA with getters and setters. My dilemma is that since I need to copy the structure of the VB codes (we are forced to), I also need to include the query services in my JAVA class. But in our framework, only service classes have access to the query services.

I am thinking of changing my JAVA class to an abstact class, and use Anonymous class instead.

Sample:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
     private int a;
     private int b;

     public String calculate1() {
          // do processing for variables a and b
          String sql = "" // build sql here
          List<Map<String, Object>> result = query(sql);
     }

     public String calculate2() {
          // do processing for variables a and b
          String anotherSql = "" // build anotherSql
          List<Map<String, Object>> result = query(anotherSql);
     }

     protected abstract List<Map<String, Object>> query(String sql);

     // getters and setters for a and b
}

public class MyService {
     @Autowired
     private QueryService myQueryService;

     public void execute() {
          MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {
             @Override
             protected List<Map<String, Object>> query(String sql) {
                 return myQueryService.executeQuery(sql);
             }
          };
     }
}
```

A few things to consider:

1. My Service is a singleton-scope bean.
2. I also like MyClass to be session based (1 instance per user).
3. Since I wont be declaring the MyClass in my Spring context, it cannot use dependency injection and cannot use other services. I will be saving the instance in a session and will just be retrieving the instance of MyClass.

Also because of this dilemma, I am forced to use string queries and JDBC template. Originally, our framework uses DAO objects and Hibernate. If someone also can solve the code using DAO, that would be better. If I will be using DAO objects, I would have to use different DAO objects with their DAO service classes.

I am not entirely sure if this is a good design. I don't know also if this will work. I was not able to run this in my environment.

I would really appreciate it if someone can enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to offer relevant design advice not knowing your exact requirements. In particular "I need to copy the structure of the VB codes (we are forced to), I also need to include the query services in my JAVA class" seems weird. Would porting to another language not be the ideal time to improve the design?

Comment: We dont have a choice regarding the design. Our client gave the framework for us to work with and they don't take any change request in their framework. What I really need is as much as possible, to just copy the VB structure and logic, and apply good designs in Java (although our client doesn't really care about design, as long as it's a copy of their vb system and has the same behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an instance of `MyClass` can't function without an instance of `QueryService`, how about you just pass an reference to the query service into the constructor of `MyClass`:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    private final QueryService queryService;

    public MyClass (QueryService queryService) {
        this.queryService = queryService;
    }

    protected List<Map<String, Object>> query(String sql) {
        return queryService.executeQuery(sql);
    }
}

public class MyService {
     @Autowired
     private QueryService myQueryService;

     public void execute() {
          MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myQueryService);
     }
}
```

Making the `queryService` instance field `final`, and having such a constructor, clearly expresses this dependency in code.

Comment: I forgot about this. This is much cleaner and easier to read. Thanks!